# Dealing with rapidly changing XSDs in agile development

Tags: java, xml, xsd, automation

We are currently involved in an agile project where both new enhancements and bug fixes are coming in fast and furious, resulting in XML payloads constantly failing XSD validation. The Java software engine requires the XML and XSD to match.

To make matters worse, our target is a database whose table layouts must also keep up with the rapid changes. I have solved the database part but don't have an ideal solution for handling the XML/XSD differences quick enough.

We rely on another department to send us an up-to-date XSD whenever layouts change on their side, but they are woefully unable to keep up with the rapid pace of changes so we end up manually creating new XSD versions on our end.

I have devised a system whereby every XML file we process is validated across one of several versioned XSD files (starting from the most recent version to the oldest). This works except when no version works for a given XML, so we have to find the closest match and generate a new version. There's timestamp information in the XML and use the name of the xsd file to find its closest existing match.

I am using xsd filenames such as YYYY-MM-DD-SEQ.XSD, for example

There has to be an easier way to do this but I am not finding the way. I really do not want to invest the time to program an XSD generator but perhaps this is the best way? Is there a better, easier way?

Comment: This question is fine here (aside: the meta link provided is old.  See [**this comment**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171/whats-the-difference-between-programmers-and-stack-overflow#comment22453_171) and [*What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow*](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7182/what-goes-on-programmers-se-a-guide-for-stack-overflow)).  The real issue is the wrong expectation of the role of XSD, and that's as true here as it would be on Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 0):

> We are currently involved in an agile project where both new
>   enhancements and bug fixes are coming in fast and furious, resulting
>   in XML payloads constantly failing XSD validation. The Java software
>   engine requires the XML and XSD to match.

There's nothing wrong with agile development or rapidly evolving interface definitions<sup>1</sup>.  Validation is properly failing and providing the Java software engine with safeguards against unexpected input.  This is what should be happening until...

> I have devised a system whereby every XML file we process is validated
>   across one of several versioned XSD files (starting from the most
>   recent version to the oldest).

**Defeating the proper role of a schema is what's wrong.**

> There has to be an easier way to do this but I am not finding the way.
>   I really do not want to invest the time to program an XSD generator
>   but perhaps this is the best way? Is there a better, easier way?

No, there is no easier way to misuse a schema.  You're going to have to work hard at it and ignore the nagging feeling that something's wrong.

Or, you can back up, rework your flow, and let XSD do its job rather than struggle so to defeat it.

Updating the XSD should be done with your agile development framework to reflect the true interface definition at any point in your development.  Acceptance criteria should always involve validation against the current interface definition as specified by the XSD.

If an outside group cannot keep up, then you have a higher level issue that should be addressed directly rather than swept under the carpet.  **Either they speed up, or you slow down, or you accept the impedance mismatch and design an *explicit* transformation step to decouple the two systems and close the gap.**  The XSD versions will be your guide to the gap.  XSLT is very good at transforming XML between two versions of an XSD; it can even be used to provide mock data that the other system is not generating for real yet. If you can't match up your rates of change between the two groups, you'll at least be able to explicitly control which changes can be absorbed by which of the groups in their timeframes.

<sup><sub>[1] Well, there is something wrong if the real underlying problem is that it's simply too early in the process to be committing to an interface definition.</sub></sup>